# Are there any weapons in FO4 that are natively chambered in .50 caliber?

Tags: fallout-4

Are there any weapons in FO4 that are natively chambered in .50 caliber?

By natively chambered, I mean a gun that doesn't need a ".50 caliber receiver" mod to fire .50 caliber rounds, so that it can potentially take other receiver mods and still shoot .50 caliber bullets.

I was really looking forward to finding my first anti-materiel rifle and modding it up with a Calibrated Powerful Receiver and the other top tier sniper mods to relive the fun I had in FO:NV, sneaking around with my silenced anti-materiel rifle and one-shot-killing all the Mojave's toughest creatures with a headshot.

Sadly, I haven't been able to find any common weapons that are natively chambered in .50 caliber, preventing me from reliving that fun in FO:4.  (And no, slapping a .50 caliber receiver into something isn't even close to the same experience.)

So, while I'm pretty sure there are no common guns that are natively .50 caliber, I'm still holding out a faint hope that maybe there's a unique or rare weapon that is.  Does anyone know, one way or the other?

Comment: Can't prove the negative, but I really don't think there are. What's wrong with a sniper rifle chambered for .50?

Comment: Agree with @DCShannon. And I found my sniper with a .50 caliber receiver. It's actually quite underwhelming too, even fully upgraded.

Comment: @DCShannon Well, no "better" receiver mods for that ammo type, unlike all other ammo types (AFAIK), and well, just slapping the receiver in there is underwhelming.  It's still just a hunting rifle, and therefore looks exactly like... a hunting rifle.  In FO:NV, when I had my anti-materiel rifle slung over my back it was taller than my character was!  It was big, and impressive, and kicked like a mule on steroids... it looks and feels like a heavy weapon, instead of being a hunting rifle with an invisible damage stat increase.

Comment: @HopelessN00b That's a decent point about not being able to further upgrade the receiver. I would add that to your question to make your objections clearer. That being said, it won't be *called* a hunting rifle once you have it upgraded. It also changes color to look like the sniper rifle in previous games, especially with a Marksman or Recoil-Compensating Stock.

Comment: @DCShannon It'd be ideal if the .50 was the native ammo type for a gun, save the receiver slot to upgrade it further. Honestly, if .50 ammo is ONLY used on guns that have the .50 cal receiver mod upgrade, I don't see myself using my .50 ammo at all. I'd rather upgrade the gun with a powerful receiver instead...

Comment: @king14nyr The .50 Cal does a lot more damage than the powerful receiver. It's significantly better. I don't understand the objection.

Comment: @king14nyr Well, the .50 caliber receiver provides a drastic damage improvement over a hunting rifle with even the best .308 receiver, so the receiver is an improvement from a damage statistic perspective, but from a gameplay perspective, it's no different, and it should be. A .50 caliber weapon IRL is big and impressive and powerful and has a recoil that feels like the power of the gods pulsing through your body.  In FO:NV, the .50 caliber guns reflected that, in FO:4, just adding an ammo type receiver makes no difference to the way the gun feels.  Which is disappointing, comparatively.

Comment: @DCShannon Sorry, you're correct on the damage aspect, .50 rules there. I suppose it doesn't get some of the other perks of the high-level gun nut receivers. 'Calibrated Powerful' gives bonuses to accuracy and crit shot damage. Those are some enhancements that you'll never see on a .50 rifle. That's just the trade-off, I guess.

Comment: Hm, I thought that at some point I had changed the caliber on one of my weapons, and the next time I brought it up in the workbench, there was a new list of mods (like the 'Calibrated Powerful') available that used the new caliber, along with 1 choice to change it back to the  caliber it was before (as a standard receiver in that caliber).  I had a ton of weapons in my inventory though, and the naming conventions are so confusing for weapons - I may have just confused the weapon I used the caliber mod on for a whole different weapon in my inventory.

Comment: To relive the fun you had in NV you're going to need mods that increase the damage, thus removing their immersion-breaking ability to bullet sponge 700 grains of lead traveling at 3k fps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If the Fallout Wikia's Fallout 4 Weapons wiki page and table](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_weapons) is accurate and contains all information, then no, there are no base weapons that use .50 ammo.

[Their ammunition page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_ammunition) has the following weapons listed as using [.50 ammo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/.50_caliber_round_%28Fallout_4%29):

1. [Hunting rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hunting_rifle_%28Fallout_4%29)
2. [Pipe bolt-action pistol](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pipe_bolt-action_pistol)
3. [Reba II (unique weapon)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reba_II)

Comment: Thanks, +1.  I'm kind of hoping for a more definite source than a fan-wiki, so I'll hold off on accepting this for the moment... probably means I'll have to hunt through the game files myself, blech.  [The Reba II page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reba_II) has an interesting note on it though, saying If collected at a currently unknown level, the gun will instead use .50 rounds`.  Seems like a possibility worth looking into.

Comment: @HopelessN00b The fallout wiki is pretty comprehensive, I doubt you will find a more definite source than them. A lot of their info is taken from hunting through the game files anyway.

As for the Reba II, it's a unique Hunting Rifle, it just has a chance to come with a .50 receiver already installed if you are higher level. It is not a native .50. (I know because I have it).